# Creating Dynamic arrays for obtaining weekly data

Tags: .net

I need to get JSON data in the format shown below

```
{
    "SalesDetails":["Sales1,Sales30"]
    ,
    "Sales1":
    [
    {"name":"Porsche","quantity":"2"},
    {"name":"Jaguar","quantity":"30"}
     ]
}    ,
    "Sales30":
    [
    {"name":"Porsche","quantity":"29"}
     ]
}
```

The number of "Sales1", "Sales2"....is not fixed. It is dynamic. It could be 20 or 60,etc.
I cannot create that many properties in my class like

```
class x
{
 public type Sales1 {get;set;}
 public type Sales30 {get;set;}
 .....
 public type SalesN{get;set;}
}
```

Is there any way to create these as dynamic properties or any other solution and get result in the desired format?

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize the JSON data into a Dictionary object. You can then access the values in in the dictionary by concatenating "Sales" with an iterator and using that as a key or by using `foreach`.

http://procbits.com/2011/04/21/quick-json-serializationdeserialization-in-c/